Error : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
When I'm on my website page and I choose a type of equipment, I get the error ERROR : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined qui s'affiche avant même que je finisse de choisir les différentes valeurs
I try to insert it into my database, and the $numLicence variable is retrieved thanks to another page that sends it. I've already checked the variable names and they are identical to those in the database. Can you help me?
<?php
include "connPDO.php";

// Récupérer le numéro de licence depuis l'URL
$numLicence = isset($_GET['numLicence']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['numLicence']) : "";

try {
    // Récupérer les types d'équipements
    $stmtType = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT typeEquipement FROM Equipement");
    $stmtType->execute();
    $types = $stmtType->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $selectedType = isset($_POST['typeEquipement']) ? $_POST['typeEquipement'] : '';

    if ($selectedType) {
        $stmtEquip = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nomEquipement, codeEquipement FROM Equipement WHERE typeEquipement = :typeEquipement");
        $stmtEquip->bindParam(':typeEquipement', $selectedType, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtEquip->execute();
        $noms = $stmtEquip->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        $noms = [];
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Erreur : " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Ajout de l'équipement du licencié</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="fixed-header">
            <h1>FCOSK 06</h1>
            <a href="pageProtegee.php"><button class="custom-btn" id="ajt"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></button></a>
            <a href="ajout.php"><button class="custom-btn" id="ajt"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i></button></a>
            <a href="imprime.php"><button class="custom-btn" id="ajt"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i></button></a>
            <a href="cotisations.php"><button class="custom-btn" id="ajt"><i class="fa-solid fa-money-check-alt"></i></button></a>
            <a href="logout.php"><button class="custom-btn" id="ajt"><i class="fa-solid fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button></a>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="listeDeroulante">
                <form action="ajoutE.php" method="POST">
                <?php
    include "connPDO.php";
    session_start();
    $numLicence = isset($_GET['numLicence']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['numLicence']) : "";
    $errors = [];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['numLicence'])) {
        $numLicence = isset($_POST['numLicence']) ? $_POST['numLicence'] : "";
        $tailleEquipement = isset($_POST['tailleEquipement']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['tailleEquipement']) : "";
        $distribué = isset($_POST['distribué']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['distribué']) : ""; // Valeur par défaut
        $dateDistribution = isset($_POST['dateDistribution']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['dateDistribution']) : "";
        $nomEquipement = isset($_POST['nomEquipement']) ? $_POST['nomEquipement'] : "";


        var_dump($numLicence);
        var_dump($tailleEquipement);
        var_dump($distribué);
        var_dump($dateDistribution);
        var_dump($nomEquipement);

        try {
            // Récupérer le code d'équipement associé au nom d'équipement sélectionné
            $stmtCode = $pdo->prepare("SELECT codeEquipement FROM Equipement WHERE nomEquipement = :nomEquipement");
            $stmtCode->bindParam(':nomEquipement', $nomEquipement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtCode->execute();
            $codeEquipement = $stmtCode->fetchColumn();

            // Insérer les données dans la table distribEquipement
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO distribEquipement (codeEquipement, tailleEquipement, distribué, dateDistribution, numLicence) VALUES ( :codeEquipement, :tailleEquipement, :distribué, :dateDistribution, :numLicence)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':codeEquipement', $codeEquipement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':tailleEquipement', $tailleEquipement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':distribué', $distribué, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dateDistribution', $dateDistribution, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':numLicence', $numLicence, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            header("Location: pageProtegee.php");
            exit;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "<p>Erreur : " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()) . "</p>";
        }
    }
?>


                    <label for="numLicence">Numéro de licence :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="numLicence" name="numLicence" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($numLicence); ?>" readonly>

                    <label for="typeEquipement">Type d'équipement :</label>
                    <select id="typeEquipement" name="typeEquipement" required onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="">Sélectionnez un type</option>
                        <?php foreach ($types as $type): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($type['typeEquipement']); ?>" <?php echo ($type['typeEquipement'] === $selectedType) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($type['typeEquipement']); ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>


                    <label for="nomEquipement">Nom d'équipement :</label>
                    <select id="nomEquipement" name="nomEquipement" required onchange="updateCodeEquipement()">
                        <option value="">Sélectionnez un nom</option>
                        <?php if (!empty($noms)): ?>
                            <?php foreach ($noms as $nom): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($nom['nomEquipement']); ?>" data-code="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($nom['codeEquipement']); ?>">
                                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($nom['nomEquipement']); ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </select>

                    <!-- Champ caché pour stocker le code d'équipement -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="codeEquipement" name="codeEquipement" value="">

                    <label for="taille">Taille :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="tailleEquipement" name="tailleEquipement">

                    <div class="radio-container">
                        <label><input type="radio" id="distribue_oui" name="distribué" value="1" required>Oui</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" id="distribue_non" name="distribué" value="0" required>Non</label>
                    </div>

                    <label for="date">Date de distribution :</label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateDistribution" name="dateDistribution">

                        <div class="terminer">
                            <button class="custom-btn" id="ajt" type="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button class="custom-btn" id="ajt" type="reset"><i class="fa-solid fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>


According to this answer, parameters and placeholders must be alphanumeric ascii, so distribué would not be valid

} catch (PDOException $e) {     echo "Erreur : " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage());     exit; }...this is pointless. You're just replicating what PHP will do automatically if an error occurs. Except that you've also made it worse, because you have removed the flexibility to log errors (and show a friendly error page to the user, without any potentially compromising technical info exposed in it) in your live environment. Errors should only reach the front-end when you're in development mode. Read this for more information: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors
